# How to make a GrahpQL Mutation with nested schema

Tags: javascript, api, graphql

I have been writing an API that uses GraphQL.  I am still pretty new to it, and have been running into some problems regarding mutations.  A simplistic form of my API has two record types.  There is a contact record and a tag record.  A contact record can have multiple tag records associated with it.

The schema I wrote for each of these record types are below:

```
const Tag = new graphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'Tag',
description: 'Categorizes records into meaningful groups',
fields: () => ({
  _id: {
    type: graphQL.GraphQLID
  },
  name: {
    type: graphQL.GraphQLString
  }
 })
});

const Contact = new graphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'Contact',
description: 'Contact record',
fields: () => ({
  _id: {
    type: graphQL.GraphQLID
  },
  name: {
    type: graphQL.GraphQLString
  },
  tags: {
    type: new graphQL.GraphQLList(Tag),
    resolve: function(src, args, context) {
      return TagModel.findByContactId(src._id)
        .then(tags => {
          return Promise.map(tags, (tag) => {
            return TagModel.findById(tag.tag_id);
          });
        });
      }
    }
   })
  });
```

I can make a mutation easy enough on records such as tags since they don't contain nested records of their own, but I'm not sure how to make a mutation on a record like contacts since it can contain tags as well.  The mutation code I put in place looks like this:

```
const Mutation = new graphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'Mutation',
fields: {
  createContact: {
  type: Contact,
  description: "Create Contact",
  args: {
    name: {type: new graphQL.GraphQLNonNull(graphQL.GraphQLString)},
    tags: {type: new graphQL.GraphQLList(Tag)}
  },
  resolve: function(source, args) {
    return ContactModel.save(args.name);
  }
  } 
 }
});
```

I'm not sure how to complete the resolver in the mutation in order to be able to save a contact and tag records at the same time.  For instance, if I made a mutation query to save a new contact record with a new tag like this:

```
{"query": "mutation createNewContact { 
contact: createContact (name: "John Smith", tags { name: "family" } ) 
{_id, text, tags { name } } }" }
```

Is there something special that I need to do in my mutation schema in order to allow for this type of mutation to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `Tag` as an input object type, you would have to create a type like `TagInput`

```
const TagInput = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
    name: 'TagInput',
    fields: {
        _id: { type: GraphQLID },
        name: { type: GraphQLString } 
    }
});
```

It is recommended to always create `Input` version of your normal type. You could do the same with `Contact` by creating `ContactInput`. Then you could create a mutation in very similar way you did it

```
const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        createContact: {
            type: Contact,
            args: {
                contact: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(ContactInput) },
                tags: { type: new GraphQLList(TagInput) }
            },
            resolve: (root, args, context) => {
                console.log(args);
                // this would console something like
                // { contact: { name: 'contact name' },
                //   tags: [ { name: 'tag#1' }, { name: 'tag#2' } ] }
                // here create contact with tags
            }
    }
});
```

The `query` you would run would look like that

```
{
    "operationName": "createContact",
    "query": "mutation createContact($contact: ContactInput!, $tags: [TagInput])
              {
                  createContact(contact: $contact, tags: $tags) {
                      _id
                      text
                      tags {
                          name
                      }
                  }
              }",
    "variables": {
        contact: { name: "contact name" },
        tags: [ { name: "tag#1" }, { name: "tag#2" } ]
    }
}
```

Comment: That works.  Thanks!  I do have a problem though with getting the tags data back in the response.  Even when I just return the args in the resolver when doing nothing else all of the properties come back, but tags is just an empty array.  Something like { contact: _id: 1, name:"John", tags: [] }.  Am I missing something that is necessary for the tags data to be returned?